# Bash cut end of string with dynamic length

Tags: bash, cut

Perhaps my question is easy, but I can't figure out how to do this.

In a bash script I have a variable with stored snmp SysObjectID ($device_manufacturer).
The values of this variable can be like:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.2066
1.3.6.1.4.1.2272.9
1.3.6.1.4.1.2272.7
1.3.6.1.4.1.45.3.30.1
1.3.6.1.4.1.930.1.1
1.3.6.1.4.1.930.1.4
1.3.6.1.4.1.930.1.5
```

I need to cut from this value and put in another variable value starts with 1.3.6.1.4.1 and digits that goes after point and limited by point. For example:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.9
1.3.6.1.4.1.2272
1.3.6.1.4.1.45
```

I've tried to use cut, but it returns only digits after 1.3.6.1.4.1

Please help me how to rewrite command to return right value:

```
unknown_device_manufacturer=$( echo $device_manufacturer0 | cut -d'.' -f7 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are close:

```
unknown_device_manufacturer=$( echo $device_manufacturer0 | cut -d'.' -f1-7 )
```

or

```
unknown_device_manufacturer=$( echo $device_manufacturer0 | cut -d'.' -f-7 )
```

From `cut` man page:

> N-M    from N'th to M'th (included) byte, character or field
>
> -M     from first to M'th (included) byte, character or field